# Unable to do laravel relationships using laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys, relationship

I am facing issue regarding storing ids and display their values from two different table i have 1 table business_master and other table is page_master i have combine business_name column with page_url column which are available on page_master table if i add my business and page first time its successfully combine these two values as one business can have many pages and if i only add page 2nd time i am unable to see business_url with page_url column.

My Page Model:

```
class PageList extends Model
      {
protected $table = 'page_master';


protected $fillable = ['business_id', 'page_url', 'page_name'];


public function business()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Business','business_id');
}

   }
```

and in my view:

```
 <td>{{optional($value->business)->business_url}}.spikesales.io/{{$value->page_url}}</td>
```

This is my first time out if i add business_url and page_url

```
    hussain.spikesales.io/house
```

and then if i add only page the out put is something like that

```
   .spikesales.io/hello
```

one business can have many page it should attach business_ url also but i am unable to find solution:

Any help will be highly appreciated!

```
    public function pageListHere()
{
    $list = PageList::all();
    return view('page-list',compact('list'));
}
```

Comment: You should post the controller code where you are fetching the data and passing it to view.

Comment: i added controller code please see.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your controller code like this:

```
$list = PageList::select('*');
$list->with(
                array('business'=>function($query){
                    $query->select('*');
                }));
$pageList = $list->get();
return view('page-list',compact('pageList'));
```

The varialbe $pageList will be having all the rows of that table along with related Business table rows.

Comment: and which variable i will pass in my view

Comment: <td>{{optional($value->business)->business_url}}.spikesales.io/{{$value->page_url}}</td> here

Comment: i have foreach loop in my view $list as $value

Comment: Please check the updated answer. And change your variable name in loop with `$pageList` and it will work.